# React button type changed while passing in a value

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

So Im working on React with flowtype, and I have a value with a type of say `ItemType`, and it is an object of different properties.

For example, if I declare `item: ItemType`, and in console log item will print out

```
Item { Property1: 'someValue', Property2: 'someValue', Property3: 'someValue'}
```

I am trying to pass in the variable as a value, such as

```
<button value={item} onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Click Me!</button>
```

Supposedly the `item` I passed into the value is an `ItemType`, but when I checked the type it becames a string. I tried console logging the type inside the callback function as below

```
onButtonClick = event => {
  console.log("type checking: " + typeof event.target.value); // Output: type checking: string
}
```

I don't know why this is happening as I need the variable to be the correct type instead of string. Can anyone explain this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons `value` attribute is associated with its name when submitting a HTML form, have a read of the prop here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

To achieve what I believe you want you can try this:

```
<button onClick={() => this.onButtonClick(item)}>Click Me!</button>
```

You should then have access to the item object inside the `onButtonClick` method.

```
onButtonClick = item => {
   console.log(item)
// output: { Property1: 'someValue', Property2: 'someValue', Property3: 'someValue'}
}
```